# Green Check through SAP info box

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am running a script and need to green check through this info box on certain items. I have tried doing this with the below but it's not working. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set OBJECTSAP = SapSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtMESSAGELINE", False)
If Not OBJECTSAP Is Nothing Then
SapSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
End If
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, post the code itself (edit your question) so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: Still not working. Maybe I have the wrong code? In certain instances I just need to press the green check on the info box shown above.

Comment: `Set OBJECTSAP =SapSession.findById("wnd[1]",False)` should be sufficient.